# PCB Design for an RF application

Tags: rf, wireless, nrf24l01

I am designing a PCB that will have a wireless RF IC on it. It uses the NRF24L01+ ([datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/nRF24L01Pluss_Preliminary_Product_Specification_v1_0.pdf)) and an RF Front End RFX2401C ([datasheet](https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/1966930/0/0/1/rfx2401c.html)).

I know that the PCB layout is very important for RF applications, so I tried to look up and follow as many rules as I could. I am limited by my design constraints to a two-layer, 1.6mm, standard FR-4 board. This is also a low-cost design.

Here is a list of the rules that I found online and tried to apply to my design.

1. Ground Planes
2. ALOT of vias (though I would like an explanation of why)
3. Small 0402 component parts
4. Shortest possible trance length
5. No Ground Plane under the antenna to avoid signal reflections

Is there anything that I am missing or that I got wrong?

Here is the schematic that I have created.
[image]

And the following board layout:
[image]

Comment: Your ground planes don’t seem to connect to your ground net, for example at the antenna connector.

Comment: @ThePhoton for whatever reason, I thought you were not supposed to connect the ground of the antenna connector. After going back and looking, I can see I was very wrong! Thank you for catching that!

Comment: the split top side ground plane looks unintentional, one way or another: I'd bet you'd be better off with one continuous ground plane, but you seem to be intentionally breaking horizontally. Also, not a great break in ground plane if the bottom ground plane is continuous below: That's just a capacitor that you've build, potentially feeding the top "patch" as antenna. Also, while certainly short, you should definitely match all your microstrip lines in impedance, and thus, the trace connecting your SMA center conductor to the first passive component should be surrounded by ground.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thanks for the input! I have added the ground plane around the SMA connector to match impedance. For the ground plane, should I make it continuous across the entire board, or have a completely separate ground plane for the wireless section that connects to the other ground at a single point?